# Units in ring theory

Tags: ring-theory

How to determine  $U( Z[i])$

I tried this

$$(a+bi)(c+di) = 1,$$

where $a,b,c,d$ are integers.  and compared real no. With real

Comment: Did you even try to Google this? There are plenty of arguments showing how to determine the units of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. For example, this: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/Zinotes.pdf

Comment: Also, this exact question had already been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108071/units-of-gaussian-integers

Answer (score 2):

Hint: note that if $a+bi$ is invertible, then the corresponding complex number must have norm $1$.

(In general, considering the norm is very often a good thing to do in this ring.)

Answer (score 1):

You can show that if $(a+bi)(c+di)$ is an integer, then $c=a, d=-a$. So the problem reduces to solving $$(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2=1$$

What can you say about the integers $a,b$ if the above should be true?