# What are the unit elements in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, gaussian-integers

What are the unit elements in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, where $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is defined to be the set of Gaussian integers ?
My progress: My mentor gave this problem and he said to use determinants and scalefactor.
Then I was able to proceed and got the unit elements in $\Bbb{Z}[i]=1,-1,i,-i$ , which is correct . However, I wonder if there is some other way to proceed .

Any solution or hint is appreciated .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual approach is to consider $|z|^2$ for $z\in\Bbb Z[i]$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng can you give a hunch on how to proceed ..

Comment: What is $|z|^2$ if $z=a+bi$?  What is $|z|^2$ if $z$ is a unit?

Comment: we have  N(z)=a^2+b^2, if z is a unit then it must divide 1 , so N(z)|+-1,is it okay till now ?

Comment: Okay I got it thanks :) .
we have a^2+b^2= 1 or -1 . proceeding we get z=1,−1,,−

Comment: and $N(z)$ can't be $-1$ because $a^2+b^2$ can't be negative

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108071/units-of-gaussian-integers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a+bi$ is a unit ($a,b$ are integers) then for some integers $c,d$ we have $$(a+bi)(c+di)=1.$$ Then the norms of the LHS and RHS should be the same. To get the norm of the LHS, we multiply by $a-bi$ and $c-di$, we get  $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$. So $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=1$. Since both factors are non-negative integers, both are equal to 1. So $|a+bi|=1$. Conversely if $|a+bi|=1$ then $a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)=1$ so $a+bi$ is a unit. For integers $a,b$
$a^2+b^2=1$ is possible iff $a=\pm1, b=0$ or $a=0, b=\pm1$. Thus there are four units: $1,-1, i, -i$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If the norm of a gaussian integer is defined by $N(a+bi)=a^2+b^2$, then this norm is multiplicative.  That is, $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$.